# How is Open Interest calculated?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, market-data, open-interest

(More specifically on crypto exchanges)

If traderA opens 1 long and traderB closes 1 long, thus delta Open Interest is 0. Then what if traderA opens 1 long, and traderB opens 1 short, is delta Open Interest = +1 or +2?

There seems to be a bit mixed information on the web, and can't figure out the exact definition of how exchange Open Interest is calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every futures contract has a buyer and a seller. Open interest just counts the number of contracts people hold.
If that number equals `100`, then there are that number of buyers and sellers.

In your example, are traderA and traderB all the traders in the market? If so, they're trading the same contract and open interest increases by 1. Otherwise, there are other traders in the market (say traderC and traderD), which are taking the opposite side in those trades. In that case, open interest would increase by 2.